# Rails belongs_to and single table inheritance not behaving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, single-table-inheritance, nested-attributes, belongs-to

I have a `Bike` model and a `Component` model. Several models inherit from `Component`: `Frame`, `Chain`, `Crankset` etc.

When I submit my form, my params look like this:

```
"bike" => { "frame" => { "id" => "4" }, "chain" => { "id" => "19" }, ... }
```

In my controller, the following code breaks:

```
@bike = Bike.new(params[:bike])
> Frame(#90986230) expected, got HashWithIndifferentAccess(#81888970)
```

If I hack my form to generate the following params, it works:

```
"bike" => { "frame_id" => "4", "chain_id" => "19" ... }
```

Here's my models:

```
class Bike < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :frame
  belongs_to :chain
  ...
end

class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bikes
end

class Frame < Component
end
```

Single table inheritance is working - I can call `Frame.first` and `Component.all` without issue.

Am I going insane? Isn't the nested params the usual convention? That's what gets generated by:

```
- f.fields_for @bike.frame do |frame|
  = frame.hidden_field :id
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your `Bike` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using nested forms, so nested params should work if you use the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` tag (see [railscast 196/197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)).

```
belongs_to :frame
accepts_nested_attributes_for :frame
```